# Update nested JSON data in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Does anyone know how to update the `DataColumns` using the below library after the initial load?

I want to pass new values to the `updateData function` and have it update the grid, but nothing happens.

I've tried everything and had no luck.

I'm using this [library][1].

```js
    function updateData (value1,value2)
    {

        $('#example).columns ({
        data:[
        {‘phone’:'data','testing2':value1},
        {'testing':phone,'testing':value2},
        {'testing':data,'testing':value3},
        ]);

    }
```

```
UPDATE: 
    
   function updateData (value1,value2)
   {
       data=[
            {‘phone’:'data','testing2':value1},
            {'testing':phone,'testing':value2},
            {'testing':data,'testing':value3}];

            $('#example').columns (data); // for the initial load
    
            $('#example').columns('setMaster',data); //nothing happens after the refresh
    
        }
```

Comment: Try `$('#example').columns('setMaster', data);` where data is your json array. Tell me if that work or not then we'll try something else from the documentation

Comment: Everything is given here http://michaeleisenbraun.com/columns/  and I see 2 solutions here for your problem

Comment: No, unfortunately, that doesn't work....I'll update the main comment with what I tried

Comment: Let me know what you think.  The setMaster doesn't work as shown above

Comment: Try keeping the data format same. I mean the key value pairs

Comment: Next the last solution is to destroy the table and recreate it again using `$('#example').columns('destroy');` and then `$('#example').columns(data);`

Comment: That's all I can help with. I would still say that keep the key values same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by retrieving the column has an object and calling the setMaster(data)

```
function updateData (value1,value2)
{
       data=[
            {‘phone’:'data','testing2':value1},
            {'testing':phone,'testing':value2},
            {'testing':data,'testing':value3}];

         var $test = $('#example').columns({
               data: data

           });

           $test.setMaster(data);
               $test.create();
 }
```